# Hive bucketing based on a string column value

Tags: hive, hdfs, partitioning, bucket

I understand we can partition a hive table based on a column and apply a filter to insert records through static or dynamic partitioning.

But if I'll need to bucket based on a particular column value, how do I do that?
Let us say I have users from 500 different countries
username string
country string

If I need to create a hive table and bucket it based on country, is that possible? ideally one bucket per country.

Comment: BTW there are only 195 countries https://www.worldometers.info/geography/how-many-countries-are-there-in-the-world/

Comment: yep.. its an illogical example I chose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to cluster your data based on country. and you need to define the number of buckets based on the total number of countries.

for e.g. if there are data coming in from 500 countries, then the following should do:

```
create table (
 name string,
 country string
) clustered by (country) into 500 buckets;
```

But having said that, I would suggest you to go for `dynamic partitioning` for better query plan.

Comment: Ok. I get the partitioning side of it. But I dont yet understand the bucketing side and how it improves performance.